# How do I select an image element that has a parent of a certain id?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors, selector

```
<div id="someId_123">
     <img class"testClass"/>
</div>
```

Using JQuery, I want to select this image based on its class, and the fact that the div has "123" in its id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div[id*='123'] img.testClass")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `'[id*="123"] > .testClass'`. The `>` specifies a parent child relationship.

Comment: But you are using a fixed id, the question is to specify an id that contains 123 anywhere.

Comment: Well then the combination of this and the other answers should get him there then.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do:

```
$("div[id*=123] img.testClass")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(":div[id*=123] img.testClass");
```

Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/EdTF8/2/

You also have a typo in your HTML code:

```
<img class"testClass"/>
```

should be:

```
<img class="testClass"/>
```

I spent some minutes trying to figure out why the jsFiddle wasn't working. It was just because you didn't put a `=` sign before the class name.

Answer (score 0):

This will search for 123 anywhere in ID, and grab the image with the class testClass.

`$('[id*="123"] img.testClass')`

If you want it to be dynamic just do:

`$('[id*="' + idNumber + '"] img.' + className)`

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/su6xT/2/)

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
$('img.testClass', '[id*="123"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

First grab all images with the class specified (more efficient than selecting all nodes), and then filter for images who's parent has an id matching certain criteria.

```
$('.testClass').filter(function(){ return this.parent().attr('id').match(/123/) })
```

Comment: Don't you think that instead of resorting to jQuery functions, selecting by just using CSS selectors will be faster?

Comment: @Cupidvogel it depends on the HTML - but the key factor is to select a smaller set, and then filter that - rather than selecting all elements (as most people are suggesting) or even all div's (as you are). If you use a css selector, jQuery will split the string and run functions on it anyway - so I don't see much difference. Also, it is worth noting that CSS3 selectors, although initially had a speed advantage, no longer have an advantage over jQuery selectors.

Comment: If the selector expression contains just a raw CSS selector, jQuery will just pipe it through the CSS `queryselector` method, which being a native method, runs faster. I didn't know it myself until a few days ago, when I learnt it the hard way (lots of donwvoting, just like the one you have already received!)

Comment: It is a false assumption to guess that native means faster - as recent performance enhancements to jQuery's selector engine actually tend to outperform browser implementations. Run the tests here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-benchmark/3 and you will find that `$('#parent').find('.child')` is much faster than `$('#parent > .child')`.

Comment: If anything, my use of regex is probably what would slow down the query. I stand by my answer - I think it is versatile, allowing many tests, and the principle of selecting a small set for efficiency is adhered to.